# ASP.NET LinkButton causes postback but doesn't call specified method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have this method defined since I will add a link button to each row in a long table. However it does not call the eventHandler. It does cause a asyncPostback but never calls the eventHandler.

```
public static void InsertLinkButton(string text, string id, EventHandler eventHandler,
        UpdatePanel updateSummary, PlaceHolder placeHolder)
{
    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
    link.Text = text;
    link.Click += eventHandler;
    link.CausesValidation = false;
    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = link.ID = "link" + id;
    trigger.EventName = "Click";
    Utils.Tag(link, placeHolder);
    updateSummary.Triggers.Add(trigger);
}
```

The event handler's signiture:

```
protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check which link clicked me and do stuff
}
```

I would call the method with this:

```
InsertLinkButton("Division", "Division", link_Click, updateSummary, placeHolderSummary);
```

Is something in this code wrong? Or is my problems elseware?

Comment: Check your calling code.  You'd get a compile error with this.  You're requiring five arguments and only sending four.

Comment: Yeah I copy/pasted the wrong calling code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your button has been inserted to the page before the click event is handled, otherwise the postback has no work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling your insert early enough in the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) [lifecycle](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm)?

If you're wiring the click event up too late, you'd never have the event raised.

Try moving the call into the Page Init.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Giving the LinkButtons an ID solved it for me.